# Webbrowser control in winform showning html with parameters (Google Maps)

Tags: winforms, google-maps-api-3, webbrowser-control

I have a winform client, that contains a webbrowser control inside it. Working with C# in visual studio, and running a MSSQL for persistance.
My goal is:

> Take the data stored in my MSSQL (handle via DBML/DataContext), and show a marker on a google map (Javascript v3) for each address I got in the database.

Right now I have an HTML file in my app solution, with the JS code for showing a Google map like this (lets call it mymap.html):

```
var map;
var _geoLocationsArr = [
    ["Tranehavevej 10, 2450", "Fiberby"],
    ["Tranehavevej 8, 2450", "Fiberby"],
    ["Tranehavevej 6, 2450", "Fiberby"],
    ["Tranehavevej 4, 2450", "Fiberby"],
    ["Johan Kellers Vej 27, 2450", "Service"],
    ["Johan Kellers Vej 25, 2450", "Service"],
    ["Johan Kellers Vej 23, 2450", "Service"],
    ["Johan Kellers Vej 21, 2450", "Service"],
    ["Johan Kellers Vej 24, 2450", "Potentiel"]
        ];
        var customIcons = {
            Fiberby: {
                icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
                shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png',
                title: 'Fiberby'
            },
            Service: {
                icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
                shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png',
                title: 'Service'
            },
            Unknown: {
                icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_gray.png',
                shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png',
                title: 'Ukendt'
            }
        };
        var geocoder;

        function initialize(lat, lng) {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            //geocodeMe();
        }

        function toggle() {
            initialize(55.66718, 12.5411);
            for (var i = 0; i < _locations.length; i++) {
                var item = _locations[i];
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item[0], item[1]);
                var icon = customIcons[_locations[i][1]] || {};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: icon.icon,
                    shadow: icon.shadow,
                    title: "Hello World! " + i
                });
            }
        }

        function toggleGeocodes() {
            initialize(55.66718, 12.5411);
            for (var i = 0; i < _geoLocationsArr.length; i++) {
                geocodeMe(_geoLocationsArr[i][0], _geoLocationsArr[i][1]);
            }
        }

        function geocodeMe(address, type) {
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
                },
                function(result, status){
                    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                        map.setCenter(result[0].geometry.location);
                        var icon = customIcons[type] || customIcons['Unknown'];
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: icon.icon,
                            shadow: icon.shadow,
                            position: result[0].geometry.location,
                            title: icon.title
                            });
                        } else{
                        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                    }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize(55.665919, 12.55482)">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</body>
```

When I hit the "Geo toggle" button in my winforms, it shows the markers on the map for each geocoded address in _geoLocationsArr. And everything is working perfect.

But! Now, I want to replace the _geoLocationsArr with data generated from my winform, where my winform creates the marker data (xml, or string array, it doesn't really matter what format for me, what matters is that it can send data from the winform to the JS in the HTML page).

So, how can I create data within my WinForm, and when clicking the button calling the JS html page with the data the form has created as a parameter?
So when calling function toogleGeocodes() it will have the data as a parameter like function toggleGeocodes(_myGeoLocationsArr[]) where _myGeoLocationsArr[] is something that the winform has created and sended as parameter when calling the function.